# Update path of attributes to a new path

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a layer with photos that are linked/displayed through the path attribute. Now I need to move this path and need to update it. I could of course create a whole new file but I wonder if it could be done with the field calcualtor?

Example of my path: `C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/Map1/Map2/Picture.JPG`

So what I would like to do is that I can simply replace section `C:/Users/Adam/Desktop` with for example: `D:/GIS*/Map1/Map2/Picture.JPG`

Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: Is the part of the path, which is to be replaced, the same for all features? And is the part, which will be pasted, also the same?

Comment: Yes. It is the same for all features. They are in a map and I need to move the to a nother drive. So I just need to replace the first part of the path  "C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace`

```
replace("path",'C:/Users/Adam/Desktop','D:/GIS')
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked great